# Open Insert HyperLink Dialog in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, hyperlink, insert

**Scenario:** I need to be able to copy the access functionality where "Right Click, then go to hyperlink, then edit hyperlink, find the photo and click ok to add the link to the image ". Our users now only have access to the runtime and can no longer accomplish this.

**Problem:** I have searched on the internet and it tells me to use Application.Dialogs to open the dialog. Only problem is that I don't have that option. Would anyone be able to tell me which reference I need to add to accomplish this? Or is there another way to open that dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future users trying to accomplish this I ended up having to send the key press to open the dialog box. You need to remember to set the focus back onto your textbox before sending the key or else it won't work.

```
Private Sub Command24_Click()
Text35.SetFocus
SendKeys ("^k")
End Sub
```

Comment: Terrible solution! SendKeys is ALWAYS a mistake.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton, Then please provide me with a better one. Theres supposed to be Application.Dialogs but I dont have that collection and I couldn't find the right reference anywhere. This was the only solution I could find.

Comment: The solution is to not use hyperlink fields so you don't have to edit them. You could also look up the storage format of the hyperlink field and then you'd be able to do the editing in VBA code.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton, They have been using hyperlink fields since they "wrote" the program however many years ago. Its to late to change it. I'm only trying to get the program to work with the access runtime then I can move on to bigger projects. This is low priority at the moment.

Comment: It's never too late to change. If you end up having to do awful things like SENDKEYS, then it seems to me that it's justified to fix the fundamental error, i.e., using a storage format that's an end-user format, and not helpful for real data manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdEditHyperlink
```

will open the Hyperlink insert / edit dialog.

"Cleaner" solution (if you can make the corresponding changes): store the path as text in your DB and open it via `Application.FollowHyperlink` on whatever event you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

I read this whole page and found a wonderful and fast solution! All I did was apply the advice to set the focus to my textbox.

Here is the subroutine that I constructed based on the above:

```
Private Sub cmdHyperlink_Click()
   Me.txtPDFLink.SetFocus
   DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdEditHyperlink
   End Sub
```

It works perfectly and is actually much easier and faster than the right-click, which I disabled to prevent users from closing the form or placing it in design mode, which they should not be doing.

Comment: This works great for bound fields but did you get it to work for unbound?

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution using `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdEditHyperlink` is to do so from a double click within the hyperlinked field.

```vb
Private Sub txtInvoiceOrReceiptLink_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
On Error GoTo HandleErr

  DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdEditHyperlink

ExitHere:
Exit Sub

HandleErr:
  Select Case Err.Number
    Case 2501 ' The RunCommand was canceled
      Resume Next
    Case Else
      MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, _
        vbCritical, "br.Form_sfrmCashInflow.txtInvoiceOrReceiptLink_Enter"
  End Select
  Resume ExitHere

End Sub
```

By using a double click for the edit dialog box you can still single click merely to follow the hyperlink. The error handling code supresses the default message when the user cancels the edit dialogue box.

This solution works well in datasheets or continuous forms (in addition to forms in standard view), given that it doesn't require nominating the relevant record and field from outside that field (as you'll need to do if you are trying to bring up the edit diolog box from a commmand button).

The one drawback is that for fields with an existing hyperlink, double click will also fire the hyperlink (to bring up whatever file/resource the hyperlink points to). That is, in addition to firing up the edit dialog box.